# Creating a Class and Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, set

I got an assignment. I have to create a class with objects. For example, the class Student. In this class I have to create certain students and then I have to assign these students to a set.

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


    def show_info(self):
        return "'{}': {}".format(self.name, self.age)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.show_info()

Mark = Students(name="Mark", age=21)
Lisa = Students(name="Lisa", age=19)
```

So my question is how do I add these Objects(Mark,Lisa) to a set(). I'd be grateful if someone can give me some hints.

Comment: `students = set([Mark, Lisa])`. Or, combing the lines: `students = set([Students(name="Mark", age=21), Students(name="Lisa", age=19)])`. Or use the `{}` notation for a set: `students = {Mark, Lisa}`.

Comment: `set([Mark, Lisa])`. `set` takes an iterable, not an arbitrary sequence of elements.

Comment: Note that it is probably good to name your class `Student`: singular, not plural. While you can create multiple students with your class, each individual object is one single student, hence a `Student` class.

Comment: You can use curly brace literals to make sets as well

Comment: Use `typing.NamedTuple` for a quick way to solve your problem - see also my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the class instances `Mark` and `Lisa` themselves to be added to a set, a simple way in Python 3 is to make use of [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) -- which are essentially just regular classes under the hood -- and pass the `unsafe_hash` parameter to the decorator, so that a `__hash__` method is automatically generated for us, as shown below.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Student:
    name: str
    age: int

    def show_info(self):
        return "'{}': {}".format(self.name, self.age)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.show_info()


Mark = Student(name="Mark", age=21)
Lisa = Student(name="Lisa", age=19)

my_set = {Mark, Lisa}
print(my_set)

# If you want to customize how `Student` objects are displayed, implement
# a __repr__ instead of __str__, or just copy the implementation directly.
Student.__repr__ = Student.__str__
print(my_set)
```

Output:

```
{Student(name='Lisa', age=19), Student(name='Mark', age=21)}
{'Lisa': 19, 'Mark': 21}
```

---

If you want to add the instances *attributes* to a set instead, you can convert each instance to a `tuple` of its attributes and pass it into the `set` constructor instead, since tuples are immutable objects and are thus hashable. This is actually a great use-case for the [`astuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple) helper function which is exported by the `dataclasses` module.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple


@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str
    age: int


Mark = Student(name="Mark", age=21)
Lisa = Student(name="Lisa", age=19)

my_set = {astuple(Mark), astuple(Lisa)}
print(my_set)
```

Output:

```
{('Lisa', 19), ('Mark', 21)}
```

---

A simplification of the above concept is to use [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead of the *dataclass* approach. This allows you to retain the type hinting support and the ability to pass keyword arguments to the constructor method as in the original example, but also makes each class instance inherently hashable, since *named tuples* are essentially `tuples` under the hood. An example usage of `NamedTuple` is shown below:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple


class Student(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int


Mark = Student(name="Mark", age=21)
Lisa = Student(name="Lisa", age=19)

my_set = {Mark, Lisa}
print(my_set)
```

Output:

```
{Student(name='Lisa', age=19), Student(name='Mark', age=21)}
```